# How do I group by in a string for reporting measures by category in said string

Tags: sql-server, string, reporting, aggregates, for-xml

Using SQL Server 2019, I am trying to aggregate rep ratings by quarter onto a single row. So the consumer can visualize in a single row ratings by quarter.

So the output is like:

```
/*  rep      |   ratings                           |      quartc               */
/*  ------   |   -------------------------------   |      ---------------      */
/*  911911   |   1,2,2,2,1 | 2,2,2,2,1 | 2,2,1,2   |      Q1M | Q2M | Q3M      */
```

or better like

```
/*  rep      |   Qtr: ratings                                  */
/*  ------   |   ----------------------------------------
/*  911911   |   Q1M: 1,2,2,2,1 Q2M:2,2,2,2,1 Q3M:2,2,1,2      */
```

I've made progress using for xml and stuff, but I can't seem get my head around how to group  by quarter inside the ratings string.
Here is some runnable code for experimentation if you've got a good idea.

```
/*  THE DATA */
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RepRatings]
(
    [row] [bigint] NULL,
    [rep] [int] NOT NULL,
    [quartc] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [rate] [varchar](3) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT [dbo].[RepRatings] ([row], [rep], [quartc], [rate]) VALUES (1, 911911, N'Q1M', N'1');
INSERT [dbo].[RepRatings] ([row], [rep], [quartc], [rate]) VALUES (2, 911911, N'Q1M', N'1');
INSERT [dbo].[RepRatings] ([row], [rep], [quartc], [rate]) VALUES (3, 911911, N'Q1M', N'2');
INSERT [dbo].[RepRatings] ([row], [rep], [quartc], [rate]) VALUES (4, 911911, N'Q1M', N'2');
INSERT [dbo].[RepRatings] ([row], [rep], [quartc], [rate]) VALUES (5, 911911, N'Q1M', N'2');
INSERT [dbo].[RepRatings] ([row], [rep], [quartc], [rate]) VALUES (6, 911911, N'Q1M', N'1');
INSERT [dbo].[RepRatings] ([row], [rep], [quartc], [rate]) VALUES (1, 911911, N'Q2M', N'2');
INSERT [dbo].[RepRatings] ([row], [rep], [quartc], [rate]) VALUES (2, 911911, N'Q2M', N'2');
INSERT [dbo].[RepRatings] ([row], [rep], [quartc], [rate]) VALUES (3, 911911, N'Q2M', N'2');
INSERT [dbo].[RepRatings] ([row], [rep], [quartc], [rate]) VALUES (4, 911911, N'Q2M', N'2');
INSERT [dbo].[RepRatings] ([row], [rep], [quartc], [rate]) VALUES (5, 911911, N'Q2M', N'1');
INSERT [dbo].[RepRatings] ([row], [rep], [quartc], [rate]) VALUES (6, 911911, N'Q2M', N'1');
INSERT [dbo].[RepRatings] ([row], [rep], [quartc], [rate]) VALUES (1, 911911, N'Q3M', N'2');
INSERT [dbo].[RepRatings] ([row], [rep], [quartc], [rate]) VALUES (2, 911911, N'Q3M', N'2');
INSERT [dbo].[RepRatings] ([row], [rep], [quartc], [rate]) VALUES (3, 911911, N'Q3M', N'2');
INSERT [dbo].[RepRatings] ([row], [rep], [quartc], [rate]) VALUES (4, 911911, N'Q3M', N'1');
INSERT [dbo].[RepRatings] ([row], [rep], [quartc], [rate]) VALUES (5, 911911, N'Q3M', N'2');
GO

/*TRIED SO FAR, IS CLOSE */
SELECT
    [RefRowInQtr] = [row], A.rep,
    ratings = STUFF((SELECT ',' + B.rate
                     FROM RepRatings B
                     WHERE A.rep = B.rep
                     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), 
    quartc = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '  ' + B.quartc
                    FROM RepRatings B
                    WHERE A.rep = B.rep
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM
    RepRatings A
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and tag the database you are using and its version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is SQL Server version 2017 or higher, you can use `STRING_AGG` instead of `FOR XML PATH` :

```
SELECT
    rep, 
    STRING_AGG(rates, '|') AS ratings, 
    STRING_AGG(quartc, '|') AS quartc
FROM
    (SELECT
         rep, quartc, STRING_AGG(rate, ',') AS rates
     FROM
         [RepRatings]
     GROUP BY
         rep, quartc) s
GROUP BY
    rep
```

Results :

| rep | ratings | quartc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 911911 | 1,1,2,2,2,1|2,2,2,2,1,1|2,2,2,1,2 | Q1M|Q2M|Q3M |

OR :

```
select rep, STRING_AGG(CONCAT(quartc, ': ', rates), '|') as ratings
from (
  select rep, quartc, STRING_AGG(rate, ',') as rates
  from [RepRatings]
  group by rep, quartc
) s
group by rep
```

Result :

| rep | ratings |
| --- | --- |
| 911911 | Q1M: 1,1,2,2,2,1|Q2M: 2,2,2,2,1,1|Q3M: 2,2,2,1,2 |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/O_l3CLC-)

Comment: Outstanding and Thank You!